# Definition of Mod and Quotient with complex arguments

Tags: functions, complex

How are `Mod` and `Quotient` defined for three real/complex arguments?  I wasn't able to find the definition.

My main surprise so far when investigating their behavior is a discontinuity between real and complex arguments.  For real x, `Mod[x,1,0]` gives a result between 0 and 1.  As soon as one adds a small imaginary part, the result's real part is now between -1/2 and 1/2.

```
Plot[Re[Mod[x, 1, 0]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Plot of Mod[x,1,0] for real x]

```
Plot[Re[Mod[x+.001I, 1, 0]], {x, -1, 1}]    (* or (x-.001I) *)
```

[image: Plot of Re@Mod[x+.001I,1,0] for real x]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't find any confirmations in the documentation, but through numerical and visual checks I *think* when at least one input to `Mod` is not real, we have

[image]

This definition doesn't equal the definition one would think to have over the reals, so my guess is a piecewise definition is used to modify the function over the real line.

## Testing

```
mod[z_, n_, d_] := z - n (Round[Re[(z - d)/n]] + I Round[Im[(z - d)/n]])
```

#### Numerical check

```
rand = RandomComplex[{-10-10I, 10+10I}, {1000, 3}];

(mod @@@ rand) == (Mod @@@ rand)
```

> ```
> True
> ```

#### Visual check

Plot the argument in the complex plane of `mod` and `Mod`:

```
With[{z = x + I y, n = 1 + I/2, d = 0.1 + 0.2 I},
  DensityPlot[
    Arg[#[z, n, d]], 
    {x, -Re[n], Re[n]}, {y, -Re[n], Re[n]}, 
    ColorFunction -> Hue, 
    Exclusions -> None, 
    PlotPoints -> 100
  ] & /@ {mod, Mod}
]
```

[image]

Plot the absolute value of both in the complex plane:

```
With[{z = x + I y, n = 1 + I/2, d = 0.1 + 0.2 I},
  Plot3D[
    Abs[#[z, n, d]], 
    {x, -Re[n], Re[n]}, {y, -Re[n], Re[n]}, 
    Exclusions -> None, 
    PlotPoints -> 100
  ] & /@ {mod, Mod}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `Floor[]` and not `Round[]`?

Comment: I thought so too but for `d == 0`, `Round` has cuts as a box centered at `z == 0` rather than having cuts on the real line like `Floor` would leave. So maybe that's why it's chosen?